# Cannot withdraw money from contract

Tags: etherscan, scam, recover

I need some help please. I followed this tutorial: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU3cCZQjTJg` and used their code. I created a contract and sent 1 ETH. It did not do what it was supposed to do so I wanted to withdraw my money. But I cannot withdraw it. Could someone kindly have a look at the code and correct it in a way so I can withdraw my crypto please?